# Strange file exist with name '* (star, asterisk)'

Tags: filename

What is this strange file with name '*'
I cannot even guess..

```
$ ll
total 549M
-rw-r-----   1 jaewan eng    0 Apr 29 18:37 *
drwxr-x---  21 jaewan eng 4.0K May 20 08:21 ./
drwx------  19 jaewan eng 4.0K May  4 18:09 ../
drwxr-x---   6 jaewan eng 4.0K Apr 13 23:00 .repo/
```

Can I delete this file?

Comment: Is this located within a folder in your Home directory?
And if so... what's the address of that folder? E.g. ~/.gnome2/

Comment: If you wonder about the file's origin, beware that there is a significant chance that the file was created maliciously so to make you lose your files by issuing `rm *`.

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the empty file like this:

```
  rm '*'
```

If you do need the confirmation on delete, do this:

```
  rm -i '*'
```

Edit: You can even use backslash(`\`) or double quotes(`""`) to escape `*`.

For example: `rm -i "*"` or `rm -i \*`

Comment: Or, quote it with backslash: `rm -i \*`.

Comment: @ulidtko: yes. quote with backslash will work.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is an empty file it seems maybe created by issueing a wrong command?

Ofcourse you can remove it.

Short answer:  you can remove any file that has weird characters in it with `rm -i ?` 
Longer answer with an example: from command line I made 3 files with 1 of the being '*':

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 2011-05-21 07:13 *
-rw-r--r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 2011-05-21 07:14 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 2011-05-21 07:14 2
```

`rm -i ?` is a command you can use to remove files with 1 character long and the `-i` will ask for a confirmation on any file it matches.

Action:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp$ rm -i ?
rm: remove regular empty file `*'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `1'? n
rm: remove regular empty file `2'? n
```

After the first 'y' you do not need to asnwer the rest with 'n' but you can use <kbd>control-C</kbd> to abort the rest of the files (if there are any with 1 character).

Result:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 2011-05-21 07:14 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 2011-05-21 07:14 2
```